# How do i go about adding a two-factor authentication code to a python request?

Tags: python-3.x, api, github, request

I am putting together a post request in python for github but I am being asked to add the required two factor auth code. Do i need to add that to the payload somewhere?Any ideas? Here is the payload i am using

````
  ```r = requests.post("https://api.github.com/gists/ 
              access_token="token",
              data=data, json=data,
              auth=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth("username", 
              "password"), headers=headers)```
````

Answer (score 1):

The token should be path of the Authorization header, [as in this gist](https://gist.github.com/joshisumit/35e9ee3e68e5210af331):

```
GITHUB_API="https://api.github.com"
API_TOKEN='your_token_goes_here'
#form a request URL
url=GITHUB_API+"/gists"
print "Request URL: %s"%url

#print headers,parameters,payload
headers={'Authorization':'token %s'%API_TOKEN}
params={'scope':'gist'}
payload={"description":"GIST created by python code","public":True,"files":{"python request module":{"content":"Python requests has 3 parameters: 1)Request URL\n 2)Header Fields\n 3)Parameter \n4)Request body"}}}

#make a requests
res=requests.post(url,headers=headers,params=params,data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Source from official GitHub documentation: "[Authenticating for SAML SSO](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#authenticating-for-saml-sso)"